# Filter latest items in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda

I have this large data structure in Python - basically a list of dictionaries. Each of these dictionaries may contain a few recurring properties and a timestamp. I am trying to see if the values of these properties are the same and if so grab only the dictionary with the latest timestamp. For example:

```
[{'data': '3.50.1', 'date_time': '20131213-100308', 'version': '8.0.22'},
 {'data': '3.50.1', 'date_time': '20131230-100308', 'version': '8.0.22'},
 {'data': '3.47.0', 'date_time': '20131213-150410', 'version': '8.0.21'}]
```

The dictionaries contain many more fields but let's say these are the possible common ones that may recur. In this case, the above list should be filtered down to only two dicts - the 2nd and the 3rd one. Any smart way of achieving this without doing a double for-loop?

I tried doing lambda functions and using Python's filter but to no avail.

Comment: Is the list sorted in the sense that the repeating values are always in neighbor items?

Comment: Is every `dict` going to have the same keys, or could some have more, less, or different ones?  Also, you say you want the _latest_ of the same "data" but the first `dict` here has an earlier date?

Comment: Lev, not necessarily. They are inserted in a certain order but I am not sure how JSON decides to store it.

Comment: tjiko, every dict has the same keys. Sorry, I meant to the second dict not the first. I corrected the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the records are already "grouped" together, i.e. the records to chose from are neighboring, you can simply use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), and `max()` with `key = lambda rec: rec['date_time']` for choosing the most recent of each group (note that the way the timestamps are represented as strings, they can conveniently be compared lexicographically):

```
from itertools import groupby
recs = [{'data': '3.50.1', 'date_time': '20131213-100308', 'version': '8.0.22'},
        {'data': '3.50.1', 'date_time': '20131230-100308', 'version': '8.0.22'},
   {'data': '3.47.0', 'date_time': '20131213-150410', 'version': '8.0.21'}]

filtered_recs = []
for key, group_iter in groupby(recs, lambda rec: rec['data']):
    recent_rec = max(group_iter, key = lambda rec: rec['date_time'])
    filtered_recs.append(recent_rec)

filtered_recs
=> 
[{'data': '3.50.1', 'date_time': '20131230-100308', 'version': '8.0.22'},
 {'data': '3.47.0', 'date_time': '20131213-150410', 'version': '8.0.21'}]
```

If they are not already grouped together, you can either sort them first (potentially inefficient), like:

```
recs.sort(key=lambda rec: rec['data'])
```

Or, use this alternative, non-itertools-like, `groupby` as a replacement to `itertools.groupby` in the above solution:

```
def groupby(seq, func):
    groups = {}
    for x in seq:
        y = func(x)
        groups.setdefault(y, []).append(x)
    return groups
```

If you required that both the "data" and "version" fields should be the same, change the call to `groupby` to: `groupby(recs, lambda rec: (rec['data'], rec['version']) ):`

Comment: Seems to be working wonderfully so far. Thanks. But I am not quite sure what you mean by "if they are not already grouped together, you can sort them." Isn't that what you're doing in your solution? And how does sorting matter here?

Comment: great :) say you swap the 2nd and 3rd records, so your set is not "grouped". In the first snippet, I do not sort them, and it would not work (due to the way itertools.groupby behaves). The second snippet (the `sort` line) is meant to be called before the call to `groupby`. By sorting, you make sure your records are "grouped". Then it should work.

Comment: Oh I see. In that case I better sort them first :). It's weird for some reason it seems to be working even without sorting it first. Maybe there are flaws but I haven't looked hard enough yet. 

Btw, in your alternative solution, what would "func" be?

Comment: same thing you pass to `itertools.groupby`, i.e. `lambda rec: rec['data']`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
def findLatestDict(lst):
    latestDict = lst[0]
    latestTime = latestDict["date_time"]

    sameTimeList = []

    for aDict in lst:
        if aDict["date_time"] > latestTime:
            latestTime = aDict["date_time"]
            latestDict = aDict
            sameTimeList = []
        elif aDict["date_time"] == latestTime:
            sameTimeList.append(aDict)

    return (latestDict, sameTimeList)
```

This function will return the first dict it finds with the latest time stamp, and a list of all other dicts which have the same time stamp.

Comment: Comparing the timestamps for every dictionary in the list doesn't have much use for me when I only want to compare the timestamp for dicts that have a certain group of key-value pairs that are common.

Comment: Then you can pass that sublist that has certain key-value pairs to this function

Comment: Well, figuring out what that sublist is part of the problem.

Comment: @rexbelia you could do that pretty easily with a duct comprehension: {key: aDict[key] for key in aDict.keys() if aDict[key] == val}

Comment: Yes but what is "val" here? I don't know it beforehand. That value which consistently spans across many dicts for that one key.

Comment: Got it, I can update my answer in a bit of you'd like but it seems like the itertools answer suits you quite well

Answer (score 0):

If data is appropriately sorted you're better off using itertools.groupby.
If data is not sorted you may do something like that:

```
data = [
    {'data': '3.50.1', 'date_time': '20131213-100308', 'version': '8.0.22'},
    {'data': '3.50.1', 'date_time': '20131230-100308', 'version': '8.0.22'},
    {'data': '3.47.0', 'date_time': '20131213-150410', 'version': '8.0.21'},
]

def filtered(data):
    temp = dict()
    for row in data:

        # decorate
        stamp = row.pop('date_time')
        key = tuple(sorted(row.items()))

        # filter
        if temp.get(key, '')<stamp:
            temp[key] = stamp

    # undecorate
    for key, stamp in temp.items():
        d = dict(key)
        d['date_time'] = stamp
        yield d

for row in filtered(data):
    print row
```